# Calculating efficient use of window casing (trim)

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm working on an app that's going to estimate building material for my business. The part I'm working on right now deals specifically with trim that goes around windows.

The best way to explain this is to give an example:

Window trim is purchased in lengths of 14 feet (168 inches). Let say I have 5 rectangular windows of various sizes, all of which consist of 4 pieces of trim each (the top and bottom, and right and left). I'm trying to build an algorithm that will determine the best way to cut these pieces with the least amount of waste.

I've looked into using permutations to calculate every possibly outcome and keep track of waste, but the number of permutations where beyond the trillions once I got past 5 windows (20 different pieces of trim).

Does anyone have any insight on how I might do this.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is an algorithm question; it doesn't have anything to do with Java or Android.

Comment: P.S. You will probably also need to be clearer about what kinds of cuts are allowed (only perpendicular, or 45-degree, or any other angle?).

Comment: Is this just the classic Cutting Stock Problem or is it a variation in some way?

Comment: I believe this to be NP-complete.  Your best best is to find an approximation algorithm.  I've seen similar problems solved using genetic algorithms, but possibly you can come up with a workable solution much easier with a simple greedy aglorithm.

Comment: @harold it's a variation since you can cover one side of a window with two shorter pieces of window trim, as opposed to the classic cutting stock problem where can only cut, not join, pieces to meet the requirements. Still, my hunch is that the variation doesn't fundamentally change the nature of the problem. While it's easy to optimally compute how much trim is needed and the minimum amount of waste that can be achieved, I still think the problem of figuring out the most efficient set of cuts is going to be at least NP-hard.

Comment: @DavidZ if you can join then there's never any waste except from the last piece, and it becomes trivial

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I thought the "Cutting Stock Problem" was a joke. But turns out it's a real thing. I'm pretty sure that bit of information will aim me in a good direction. Unfortunately, joining trim is frowned upon unless the window is so long that it's required.

Comment: @harold ah, right, I misread the question and thought it was asking to minimize the number of cuts.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a typical case of the [cutting stock problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem).

I find [this lecture from the University of North Carolina (pdf)](http://www.unc.edu/depts/stat-or/courses/provan/STOR614_web/lect12_cutstock.pdf) is rather clear. More oriented towards implementing, with an example throughout, and few requirements -- maybe just looking up a few acronyms. But there are also [2 hours of video lectures from the university of Madras](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NoiPrt4OsQA) on the topic, if you want more details and at a reasonably slow pace.

It relies on solving [the knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) several times, which you can grab [directly from Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/Bounded) if you don't want to go through a second linear optimization problem.

In short, you want to select some ways (how many pieces of each length) in which to cut stock (in your case the window trim), and how many times to use each way.

You start with a trivial set : for each length you need, make a way of cutting with just that size. You then iterate : the knapsack problem gives the least favourable way to cut stock from your current configuration, and the simplex method then "removes" this combination from your set of ways to cut stock, by pivoting.

Answer (score -2):

To optimize the casements on windows and bi-fold doors for the company i worked for, i used this simple matrix - i simply took the most common openings and decided what would be the most reasonable and optimal cut lengths.

for example a 3050 window could be trimmed with waste by using one 8' cut and one 12'cut.

[image]